# Reduce memory foot print by replace anonymous class with singleton. But need to refactor the design more

Tags: java, refactoring, singleton

So I have this method that get executed repeatedly

```
public static boolean isReady(String dirPath, int numPdfInPrintJob){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    String[] fileList = dir.list(new FilenameFilter(){
        public boolean accept(File file, String filename) {
            return (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
        }
    });
    if(fileList.length >= numPdfInPrintJob) return true;
    else return false;  
}
```

This method using `anonymous class` that will create a new instance of `FilenameFilter` every time invoked and I invoke this method a lot. So I want to make this `anonymous class` into a `singleton`. So my initial thought is to create a new `singleton` class that look like this

```
public class PdfFileNameFilter implements FilenameFilter{
    private PdfFileNameFilter(){} //non-instantible

    //guarantee to only have one instance at all time
    public static final PdfFileNameFilter INSTANCE = new PdfFileNameFilter();

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
    }
}
```

Can I refactor this a bit more. I need to do `ZipFileNameFilter` as well, and maybe many different file extension filter. Dont want to create a class for each filter. I need to refactor this design a bit more. Maybe `interface` come into place somewhere here.

Comment: Have you actually measured this?  I had a similar transform where I replaced anonymous classes with static instances and found that it made little/no difference to the performance or the memory usage.

Comment: Are you sure you have to do this? Creating new objects is very cheap in java, so I would not try to optimize there.

Comment: @Jeff: I actually did not `profile` this. This is just a thought. Since I know that process this method a lot. So it might be good to reduce the memory footprint of this. It might not make a different but I dont see it cant get worse.

Comment: @tangens: I will rethink this. But if I just create a static method like `Peter` suggest below, it would definitely optimize a bit, correct. I dont see how it can get worse, correct?

Comment: The memory footprint probably should concern you, seeing as GC will remove any unnecessary instances for you. You should be worried about how many operations the method does if it being called lots and any of the answers which use a private static instance will help you reduce the amount of things your method has to do. Just keep in mind that this shouldn't be assumed to be slow, you *need* profile it to know for sure.

Comment: If this was an execution hotspot (which you'd see in profiling) I'd be more concerned about the memory and CPU impact of your accept operation. It could easily be optimized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you wanted to do was reduce memory usage you could have done

```
private static final FilenameFilter PDF_FILES = new FilenameFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File file, String filename) {
        return (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
    }
}
```

If you want to create a singleton, the simplest way is

```
public enum PdfFileNameFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    INSTANCE;

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 The first option seems like the simplest choice to me.  Why create a singleton when it is only used within the 1 class anyway.

Comment: @Robin, I agree. In my IDE you can take the original code and press <ctrl>+<alt>+C for "Introduce Constant" and it will suggest a name for the constant (based on the type and the parameter's name) and find any other places in the code which can also be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

It seems simpler to me to just use your existing anonymous class and make one instance that all your method invocations use.

```
private static final FilenameFilter PDF_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file, String filename) {
        return (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"));
    }
}

public static boolean isReady(String dirPath, int numPdfInPrintJob){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    String[] fileList = dir.list(pdfFilter);
    if(fileList.length >= numPdfInPrintJob) return true;
    else return false;  
}
```

This is a case where subclassing and making a singleton seems to be a tad overkill: you simply want only one instance to use *right here*, whereas a singleton is used when there is only one instance you will *ever* want to use.

Comment: I agree very much with this - why bother wasting time enforcing a singleton property into the class itself when you can simply *only instantiate one instance*

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `enum` for this:

```
public enum ExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    PDF(".pdf"),
    ZIP(".zip");

    private final String extension;

    private ExtensionFilter(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(extension));
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to use it like:

```
dir.list(ExtensionFilter.PDF)
```

You can also iterate through them if you need:

```
for ( FilenameFilter fileNameFilter : ExtensionFilter.values() ) {
    ....
}
```

You could also use a vararg as constructor argument to allow multiple extensions for the same filter and use the constant name as the default to make it simpler to use:

```
public enum ExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    PDF,
    ZIP(".zip", ".jar", ".war", ".ear");

    private final String[] extensions;

    private ExtensionFilter(String... extensions) {
        if (extensions.length == 0) {
            extensions = new String[] {"." + name().toLowerCase()};
        }
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        for (String extension : extensions) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(extension)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If a singleton is overkill (and I would say it is), then an enum (particularly when he didn't specify the need for zip filtering) would seem to be way overkill.

Comment: @CajunLuke: He did specify the need for zip filtering: "I need to do ZipFileNameFilter as well, and maybe many different file extension filter."  And his statement is that creating a new instance every time was overkill, and singleton was *the solution*.

Comment: Thank. I like your answer and `rachet`a lot. Thank you. So I guess in the code I would just do this `dir.list(DefaultFileNameFilter.PDF);` to filter `pdf`, correct?

Comment: +1 for simple and effective use of enums. There is no overkill here at all and the solution is elegant, effective and simple to understand

Answer (score 1):

you can step away from the full singleton and use a private field to set up the extension

```
public class ExtensionFileNameFilter implements FilenameFilter{
    private String extension;
    private ExtensionFileNameFilter (String extension){this.extension=extension;} 

    public static final ExtensionFileNameFilter PDFINSTANCE = new ExtensionFileNameFilter (".pdf");
    public static final ExtensionFileNameFilter ZIPINSTANCE = new ExtensionFileNameFilter (".zip");
    //add instances as you need

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(extension));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like this a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this just a home-made `enum` ? Lacking the possibility to use the constant name as string, to iterate the constants, to read the `ordinal()`, to serialise and others...

Comment: @costi it is but there is the possibility of making a factory method using a (weak reference) hashmap to reuse the instances and make new ones

Comment: This can be done exactly the same in an enum... except for creating new instances *of the enum type* but you can create new `FilenameFilter` instances.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I refactor this a bit more.

Yes, yes you can.

Assuming that wasn't the answer you were looking for (you should update yoru question to ask a more specific question), I wouldn't refactor it until you need it; YAGNI.

Once you have more code, like more FilenameFilters, is when you will see the possible refactorings. You will see common code, maybe an interface, stuff like that. Don't try to pre-maturely over-engineeer.

TDD is also the best way to do refactoring safely. If you have tests showing what code you actually need, lots of the extra stuff goes away, if any. And with a comprehensive test suite, you can refactor without hesitation because you know if your changes work or not based on whether your tests continue to pass.

Answer (score 1):

For interest, this alternative `accept` implementation would run much faster in a benchmark test. It does not create new stateful Objects or carry the other overhead of `String.toLowerCase`, which is not required for your case.

```
  public boolean accept(File file, String filename) {
    int offset = s.length() - 4;
    if (offset >= 0) {
      if (s.charAt(offset) == '.') {
        offset += 1;
        if (s.regionMatches(offset, "pdf", 0, 3)) {
          return true;
        } else if (s.regionMatches(offset, "PDF", 0, 3)) { 
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

If this was an execution hotspot and you were looking for optimization, something like that would help.

Comment: uhmm. Interesting. String is immutable, so `toLowerCase` will create another object. I guess in the case of load lots of files, this will definitely generate less memory footprint. But you said this would run faster as well? Even if I just load 1 file, this would run faster?

Comment: It will run faster, but unless you have a large number of invocations you will not notice. For me, the original registers elapsed milliseconds somewhere around 5000 invocations; optimized version doesn't register until around 200000. It may be irrelevant to your application - only profiling will tell you. But in execution hotspots, creation of Objects like Strings and invocation of methods such as `toLowerCase` (expensive even if without `new String`) are going to be more significant than creation of stateless Objects via anonymous inner classes which I think will be vanishingly insignificant.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great to know. What profiling tool are you using?

Comment: I have used JProfiler in the past. For above metrics I'm just using simple loops in a main method and recording time before and after using System.currentTimeMillis.     `int invocations = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        b = matches(names[j]);
        invocations++;
      }
    }
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.err.println(b);
    System.err.println(duration + " (" + invocations + " invocations)");`